# Generating Dynamic Links (Hyperlink buttons) in Windows Phone Silverlight App

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to build an app that requests a server to send a list of items ; which are displayed on the windows phone page as links.I am using WebClient.UploadStringAsync to do a POST and fetch the items. The POST works fine and I am able to get the response.

What are the options/possibilities of creating the links and adding the dynamic links to a stack panel in the UploadStringCompleted event.Also is the HyperLinkButton the option to use to create the links;I also want to do a Post when the link is clicked.

I tried using a HyperLinkButton,TextBlock within HyperLink but nothing works.

Any Suggestions?

---

Thanks a lot guys for your suggestions; the mistake that i did was to not set the TargetName property of the HyperLinkButton. I got it working after I set it right,

```
for (int i = 0; i <= itemList.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
         {

             if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(itemList[i, 1]))
                {
                   HyperlinkButton btn = new HyperlinkButton();
                   btn.Content = itemList[i, 1];
                   btn.TargetName = "_blank";
                   ItemPanel.Children.Add(btn);
                } 
}
```

Krz

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with just using a [`HyperLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) inline element?

```
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True">
    <Paragraph>
        Displaying text with <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.msdn.com">hyperlink</Hyperlink>.
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

More examples [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.navigateuri%28v=VS.95%29.aspx).

You can attach a event handler on the Navigation, and do the POST request there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `ListBox` with data binding instead of a `StackPanel`. Each row in the list will be one `HyperlinkButton`.

ListBox with item template:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding}" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code behind:

```
// handler is executed when a HyperlinkButton was pressed by user
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // get the clicked button and show its content (which is the URL)
    // (you would do your POST here)
    MessageBox.Show("Clicked URL " + ((HyperlinkButton)sender).Content);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // prepare some demo data
    List<string> urls = new List<string>();
    urls.Add("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    urls.Add("http://www.google.com");

    // set list or URLs as item source of list box; each URL will have its own button
    listBox1.ItemsSource = urls;
}
```

Comment: Meep. Stop using `HyperlinkButton` already. Mango have a element that doesn't require intensive styling to look readable.

Comment: I'll try both the options too to see the behavior and their performance. @Claus Do you mean HyperLink is a better option than the Button.

Comment: Yes, very much so. Since it's actually designed for the purpose. HyperLinkButton is a leftover from Silverlight, that requires a lot of styling to look readable.

Comment: @Claus Could I somehow bind the `RichText`'s Hyperlinks to a list of items or would I have to generate them by code?

Comment: You could add them to a `DataTemplate` as easily as any other element.  But if it's pure links, one might as well just go with regular text, and attach a command binding. (Usually HyperLink's are used in combination with text)

Comment: @Claus Ah multiple RichTextBoxes, of course. I somehow thought about binding _inside_ the RichTextBox (generating paragraphs and Hyperlinks).

Comment: No newline element for the TextBox/RichTextBox FlowDocument for Windows Phone, so yeah, not a option, sadly.

Comment: @Claus .. I don't understand when you say HyperLinkButton requires intensive styling,because the only style that I used was the 'PhoneFontSizeLarge'(from Codebehind) and everything seems to be  okay.During the trials I did try an example with Hyperlink and I din't see any big difference.